# How to adjust brightness in Fedora 17 on Sony Vaio

Tags: fedora, laptop

I have a Sony E Series laptop with Fedora 17 and Windows 8 in dual boot. 
The brightness adjusts just fine on my Windows8 but not in Fedora. If I change it with the brightness slider in the power settings nothing happens. The brightness stays maximum even if I adjust the slider to minimum.

Blinded by my screen and frustrated by the draining battery I tried everything on the net.

I tried things like -

1. Reinstall bash. `yum reinstall bash`
2. Add this to kernel parameters in grub2.cfg - `acpi_backlight=vendor`
3. Add this line to xorg.conf - `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"`
4. Add this line to grub.cfg - `"video.brightness_switch_enabled=1"`
5. Update the drivers for your video card.
6. Install some utility. Example - `xbacklight utility` from freedesktop.org

None of these suggestions worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue the command - 
`echo 500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Replace 500 with a number of your choice.

Don't take a number below 100 as that may (and probably will) turn off your screen.

Just take multiples of 100 from 500 (which is a reasonable low) to 4000 (this max may be different depending on your laptop model).

You'll need root access to execute this command.

Comment: Does this work in Lubuntu 11.10? I'd tried but the file contains the same value, 4882. Should I reboot the system?

Comment: I have these 2 folders: `acpi_video0  intel_backlight`

Comment: @Sigur What does it say when you try to change the value? You need to issue that command as root user. Type `su` at the terminal and enter the root password.

Comment: Well, nothing happens. I am using `sudo echo ....` and after the password, nothing wrong. No errors. but when I use `cat /sys/....` to check the value, it is the same, 4882.

Comment: Hello. I found the answer. Using `sudo` does not work. But with `sudo su` first to change to root and then... aha! It works! Thanks.

Comment: This command is not being saving after reboot. How to fix this? I don't want to execute this every time.

Comment: @Sigur You can put that command in a startup script. That way the command will automatically run every time you start the system.

Comment: Thanks. I did something like this, discussed here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47183/script-with-root-permission