# Script with root permission

Tags: permissions, scripting, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

I am creating a script to change the brightness of my laptop. I discovered that I can do this using

```
echo 1000  > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

for example. But I must to do this as root, not with `sudo` command. Well, I created the file `/usr/bin/brilho` containing

```
echo "$1"  > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

and now I can execute it with `brilho 1000`. But the problem is the permission. This does not work with `sudo brilho 1000` neither `brilho 100`. Again I have to change to root.

So, I would like to know how to improve this to facilitate my job.

Regards and thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much. I decided to use `sudo bash -c "..."` to do the job. But the first time, it ask password but after this, does not. Any idea?

Comment: You could also look at [xbacklight](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbacklight) to manage this for you...

Comment: @Sigur `sudo` caches your credentials when you use it, so it won't ask for a password again for a while. You can use `sudo -k` to make it forget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow arbitrary user to change brightness, you could setup sudo, invoke `visudo` to launch the editor, and put the following line at the end:

`username ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

And the script will be:

`echo $value | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Which will no longer ask your password

Comment: `sudoedit` returns `usage: sudoedit [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
                name|#uid] file ...`. I should open what file to add that line?

Comment: @Sigur mistake, should be `visudo`

Comment: I'd added that line. It's working when root user but still is asking pass when normal user. Well, one more question: should I write `username` or `my_username`?

Comment: @Sigur you need to replace that with your actual login name

Comment: It's not working. Should I reboot or closing terminal is enough? It's still asking pwd.

Comment: @Sigur try again, code edited, just found tee was in `/usr/bin/tee` instead of `/bin/tee` on Ubuntu

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. It's working now. Best wishes.